# Parse's "done" function is not executed

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have been using the api of Parse.com for some weeks and it has always worked perfectly, but from some days ago I am not able to get the information from the server. I am not aware of having changed anything about the access to parse (I must have because it is not working, but .....). The fact is that once I inicialize Parse, I am able to get the number of records of a table, but I am not able to get them.

The following code returns the number of records:

```
    Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyy");
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("tableName");

    try {

        counter = query.count();
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.d("Parse", "error count");
    }
```

but if I try to get the records:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("tableName");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("Parse", "OK");
            } else {
                Log.d("Parse", "KO");
            }
        }
    });
```

The "done" function is not executed. I have been searching the web but did not find anything.
Any ideas? It must be something silly but I cannot solve it.

Comment: Do u have internet permission in your app? Is your internet connected? What's in the logcat?

Comment: Hi, yes I have permissions and the app gets parse server, as I am able to get the number of records of the table (class) and nothing is written to the logcat